# Convert timestamp (string) to milliseconds (long)

Tags: android, date

Input is any random timestamp from the following format:

- HH:mm:ss.SS
- HH:mm:ss
- mm:ss.SS
- mm:ss
- ss.SS

Output is the milliseconds equivalent of the given timestamp

I've tried looping through each format, setting it to SimpleDateFormat then parse the string until I get matching format but I'm getting an incorrect ouput everytime.

Is there other way to implement this?

Comment: Should be pretty easy to nail down which format it is by counting colons and periods.

Comment: Without seeing your code, and the inputs and outputs, this is difficult to answer.

Comment: Also, make sure you're setting the time zone on the `SimpleDateFormat` to GMT.

Comment: @MikeM. thanks adding the GMT solves the issue for me

Answer (score 0):

It's easy with JodaTime, as you can provide multiple patterns to a DateTimeFormatterBuilder.

Add it to your build.gradle file.

```
dependencies {
    ..
    compile 'joda-time:joda-time:2.3'
}
```

Then use the following to add whichever patterns you want the parser to recognise.

```
DateTimeParser[] parsers = {
        DateTimeFormat.forPattern("HH:mm:ss.SS").getParser(),
        DateTimeFormat.forPattern("HH:mm:ss").getParser(),
        DateTimeFormat.forPattern("mm:ss.SS").getParser(),
        DateTimeFormat.forPattern("mm:ss").getParser(),
        DateTimeFormat.forPattern("ss.SS").getParser()
};

DateTimeFormatter formatter = new DateTimeFormatterBuilder().append(null, parsers).toFormatter();

DateTime date = formatter.parseDateTime("21:00:05.12");

// Millis out
long milliseconds = date.getMillis();
```